# Mysql Cookbook error RecipeNotFound: could not find recipe client for cookbook mysql

Tags: mysql, chef-infra, knife, berkshelf, knife-solo

I'm trying to provision a server with a Chef project that relied on an older version of the mysql cookbook (5.6.3). As this particular version is not compatible with anything newer that Ubuntu 14.04, I tried updating to the latest version (8.5.1) which lead to the same error. I understand that the mysql cookbook no longer provides recipes and is supposed to be a library only cookbook but it's really not clear how I'm supposed to edit the code to do what the older version did. Is there any other cookbook built on top of this one to simply install mysql client and server like the old version did or do I have to write a wrapper cookbook like the documentation seems to suggest?

Answer (score 2):

You have to write a wrapper cookbook now. The community cookbook only provides resources that you then use from that wrapper cookbook.

Answer (score -1):

You can write your own cookbook to install the specific version of mysql. You can use package chef resource

You can create a template(my.cnf.erb) for the my.cnf file and copy it over the default using the template chef resource